# In shell scripting, how to get all characters available in string before starting the digits

Tags: linux

In shell scripting, how to get all characters available in the string before starting the digit.

String is a="aaa-bbbb-19.81" or it may be "aaa-19.81"

We need to get all characters before stating the digit

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a simple Perl regex for that. This, for example, takes the given argument, and removes the first digit and anything after it:

```
$ perl -le '$_=shift; s/\d.*//; print' "aaa-bbbb-19.81"
aaa-bbbb-
```

If it needs to be included in a shell script, it could be something like this:

```sh
a="aaa-bbbb-19.81"
b="aaa-19.81"

anew=$(perl -e '$_=shift; s/\d.*//; print' "$a")
bnew=$(perl -e '$_=shift; s/\d.*//; print' "$b")

echo "$a => $anew"
echo "$b => $bnew"
```

The output:

```
aaa-bbbb-19.81 => aaa-bbbb-
aaa-19.81 => aaa-
```

If you also want the second part in a second variable, you could use a regex that captures separately any "non-digits" `(\D*)` first, followed by a digit + the rest `(\d.*)`.

In a shell scripts, that could be:

```sh
a="aaa-bbbb-19.81"
b="aaa-19.81"

read -r a1 a2 < <(perl -le '$_=shift; /(\D*)(\d.*)/ && print "$1 $2"' "$a")
read -r b1 b2 < <(perl -le '$_=shift; /(\D*)(\d.*)/ && print "$1 $2"' "$b")

echo "a1='$a1',  a2='$a2'"
echo "b1='$b1',  b2='$b2'"
```

Output:

```
a1='aaa-bbbb-',  a2='19.81'
b1='aaa-',  b2='19.81'
```

Comment: Apparenty Stackoverflow IS a coding service. I noted ZERO effort from the OP.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear to me what you want, but perhaps you're asking for:

```
$ a=aaa-bbbb-19.81; b=aaa-19.81
$ echo "${a##*[a-z-]}"
19.81
$ echo "${a%%-[0-9]*}"
aaa-bbbb
$ echo "${b%%-[0-9]*}"
aaa
$ echo "${b##*[a-z-]}"
19.81
```

Comment: The input string may be-- **a="aaa-bbb-19.81" or a="aaa-19.81"**. 
Need to split input string like.


** aaa-bbbb-19.81===> "aaa-bbbb" and "19.81"**

or 

**"aaa-19.81"=====> "aaa" and "19.81"**

Comment: You should indicate that you are using the `-` as a delimiter.

Comment: Getting rid of the hyphen is trivial: editing answer.